# Is there a good API to list GCP projects that a user can do something?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP provides very flexible privilege system which allows any project owner to give anybody any privilege to anybody. It is helpful for users but awful for administrators....

Is there any good API to list GCP projects that a user/service_account has some permissions over organization?

Comment: No. The script would need to scan every project and resource in Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a set of `gcloud` commands, I've come up with this script:

```
echo "PROJECT_ID,ROLES,MEMBERS" | cat >> output.csv
for i in $(gcloud projects list |  sed 1d | cut -f1 -d$' '); do
    echo "Getting IAM policies for project:" $i;
    echo "..........";
    paste -d "," <(printf %s "$(for j in $(seq 1 $(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].role' | cut -d "\"" -f2 | wc -l)); do echo $i; done;)") <(printf %s "$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].role' | cut -d "\"" -f2)") <(printf %s "$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].members | join(",")' | cut -d"\"" -f2)") | cat >> output.csv

    echo "Done. Logs created at file" $output.csv;
    echo "--------------------------------"
done;
```

Before running it you should have installed `jq` and `yq`:

- `pip install jq`
- `pip install yq`

At this point you can run the command (just copy and paste it on your Cloud Shell). This will create a file named `output.csv` with the IAM Policies of each project inside the organization.

Once you have this output file you can run the following command with the user/SA desired:

- `cat output.csv | grep <USER/SA>`

The output of this command will have the following structure:

`<PROJECT_NAME>,<ROLE>,<USER/SA>`

Comment: For projects, this is a good script. However, you can add IAM members to resources (KMS, Cloud Run, GCE, Storage, ...) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to find all the organizations/folders/projects with user:foo@ in their IAM policies within your org:

```
$ gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="policy:foo@bar.com resource:*cloudresourcemanager*" | egrep "resource:|role:|user:foo"
```

You can change the scope to a folder or a project.

You must have the cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies permission upon the scope.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

It doesn't cover all the policies though: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types